# Consume WCF service via ajax on asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, wcf

I have a WCF that I've created:

`http://localhost:63542/GetStoresByLocation.svc`

It will live on a different server than the page consuming it.

And I need to consume it via ajax. The public method is

`Public GetStores(<some params>) As String blahblah`

And the contract is decorated thusly:

`<OperationContract>
    <WebInvoke(Method:="GET", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>`

Here's the web config for the WCF project...

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="BRCWS.StoreLocator.GetStoresByLocation" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <!--<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="BRCWS.StoreLocator.IGetStoresByLocation" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior"/>-->
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="BRCWS.StoreLocator.IGetStoresByLocation" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>      
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

I need two things:

1. What, if anything, am I missing to be able to consume it via ajax inside an asp.net (ascx) control/page
2. what is the url for the ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

I did finally figure it out. I used a combination of the following resources:

It is not reasonable to post snippets from these resources but I will provide web archives that hopefully won't go down:

1. Build your base WCF service that resolves to an address that you can see in the WCF tester that pops up when you run your service project.
2. Implement the code as suggested here: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Consuming-WCF-Rest-Service-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx
3. Run your service and copy the address for the service from the WCF tester, add any GET params you have.
4. Resolve errors the browser gives you. They're pretty self explanatory if you just read them.
5. If you continue to have problems, go here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/97d700be-1310-4a90-bd15-8aeceb56d11e/aspnet-compatibility-mode-for-wcf-web-service
6. Your service will not show in the WCF tester because your web.config will not specify an address for the service. Thus, the tester will not find it. I suggest grabbing the address once you get a base form of the service running (so you can get the port, etc)

Links to web archives:
Link 1: https://archive.is/VefFk
Link 2: https://archive.is/XKMyH

Code snippets:

Interface:

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IGetStoresByLocation
    <OperationContract>
    <System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvoke(Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json)>
    Function GetStores(<blahblah>) as
```

Class:

```
Imports System.ServiceModel.Activation
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
Public Class GetStoresByLocation
    Implements IGetStoresByLocation
<WebInvoke(Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>
Public Function GetStores(<blahblah>) as string Implements IGetStoresByLocation.GetStores
```

Service URL:

`http://localhost:63542/GetStoresByLocation.svc/GetStores?<params in get format>`

Web config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
<services>
  <service name="BRCWS.StoreLocator.GetStoresByLocation" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="BRCWS.StoreLocator.IGetStoresByLocation" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
  </service>
</services>
```